# JQ logic for json modification

Tags: json, jq

I have system that output multiple types of JSON file with data

Is there any chance to implement above three conditions using **JQ package**? I am exploring *map*, *arg* and *argjson* command. But I am having tough time

**First JSON** of where I do have **asset** object and I want to add following key value pair

> "house": true and "colour": "orange"

```
{
    "name": "Paul",
    "country": "USA",
    "spec": {
        ...
        "asset": {
            "yard": true
        },        
    }    
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
    "name": "Paul",
    "country": "USA",
    "spec": {
        ...
        "asset": {
            "house": true,
            "colour": "orange",
            "yard": true
        },        
    }    
}
```

**2nd JSON** of where I do not have **asset** object so I want to add the object and following key value pair

> "house": true and "colour": "orange"

```
{
    "name": "Paul",
    "country": "USA",
    "spec": {
        ...
    }    
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "name": "Paul",
    "country": "USA",
    "spec": {
        ...
        "asset": {
            "house": true,
            "colour": "orange"
        },        
    }    
}
```

**3rd JSON** of where I do have **asset** object but I would like to change key value pair of house if it has set to false and set colour to orange

```
{
    "name": "Paul",
    "country": "USA",
    "spec": {
        ...
        "asset": {
            "house": false,
            "colour": "black"
        },        
    }    
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "name": "Paul",
    "country": "USA",
    "spec": {
        ...
        "asset": {
            "house": true,
            "colour": "orange"
        },        
    }    
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is - If there is no asset object -> Create asset object, put house set to true and colour ornage in the element. If there is asset object already -> check if house is set to something else AND check colour is SET to something else, if that is the case then set hosue back to true and colour to orange. If there is asset class already in place, but house and colour key is not present in the object, then add house to true and colour to orange

Comment: What have you tried?  What doesn't work?

Comment: So, if `"house"` has value `false` AND `"colour"` has value `"orange"`, do nothing?

Comment: Are each of you example objects stored in separate files? ... or are all the objects in a single file (with a comma `,` between them)? ... or are all the objects in a single array?

Comment: So basically I can retrieve json with either of these three scenario. What I want is if asset object does not contain in the JSON then add house to value true and colour orange. 
However, if we do have asset object but if there is no house or colour key but contains other key value then add house to value true and colour orange.
Additionally if you have asset object that contains either of the key either house or colour and it is already set to something else apart from true,orange respectively then make sure it has both house to value true and colour orange.

Comment: Tried something like this but did not work

`jq '.spec.asset |= if has("house") and has("colour") then . else . + { "house": true, "colour": "orange" } end | if .house == false then .house = true else . end | if .colour != "orange" then .colour = "orange" else . end' input.json`

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are storing the key-value pairs in the variable which you will pass as json argument to your query like below,

```
input='{"house":true,"colour":"orange"}'
```

Now if you use the above input in the following query all of your scenarios will work out,

```
jq --argjson input "$input" '.spec.asset+= $input' <original_file>.json
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the scenario where if you have those key but different value it overwrite it to `{"house":true,"colour":"orange"}`

Comment: @infotechsups I'm confused by your description of the desired logic.  It seems that you always want `{"house":true,"colour":"orange"}`.  Would you expand the examples in your question to show when that is not the case?

Comment: @infotechsups By `.spec.asset += {"house": true, "colour" :"orange"}`, the `asset` key within `.spec` is always created (regardless if it existed before), likewise, the `house` and `colour` keys within `.spec.asset` are always created (regardless if they existed before), and they are, respectively, set to `true` and `"orange"` (regardless what their values were before). Thus, this solution (importing `$input` by using `--argjson`) satisfies all of your requirements.

Comment: @Raj You may want to wrap the shell variable into double quotes to to not expose it to word splitting if its content is formatted slightly differently including spaces: `jq --argjson input "$input" ...`

Comment: @pmf completely agree!

Answer (score 0):

So you *always* want to have an asset with house=true and colour=orange in your output, potentially overwriting any existing values, but keeping other properties?

If that's the case, then simply merge the `asset` object with the desired properties. There is no logic involved:

```
jq '.spec.asset += {house:true, colour:"orange"}'
```

Input:

```json
{
  "name": "Paul",
  "country": "USA",
  "spec": {
    "asset": {
      "yard": true
    }
  }
}
{
  "name": "Paul",
  "country": "USA",
  "spec": {}
}
{
  "name": "Paul",
  "country": "USA",
  "spec": {
    "asset": {
      "house": false,
      "colour": "black"
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "Paul",
  "country": "USA",
  "spec": {
    "asset": {
      "yard": true,
      "house": true,
      "colour": "orange"
    }
  }
}
{
  "name": "Paul",
  "country": "USA",
  "spec": {
    "asset": {
      "house": true,
      "colour": "orange"
    }
  }
}
{
  "name": "Paul",
  "country": "USA",
  "spec": {
    "asset": {
      "house": true,
      "colour": "orange"
    }
  }
}
```